# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: ArrayList cannot be returned by getDetails()

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

here is code

```
public class TodoBusinessImpl {
        BusinessManager businessManager;

        public TodoBusinessImpl(BusinessManager businessManager) {
            this.businessManager = businessManager;
        }

        public List<String> retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring(String user) {
            List<String> filteredTodos = new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, String> test = businessManager.getDetails();
            return filteredTodos;
        }
    }
```

> what is wrong with that? what i am doing wrong

```
public class MockitoTest {  
    private BusinessManager businessManager;    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        businessManager = Mockito.mock(BusinessManager.class);
    }   
    @Test
    public void retrieveTodosRelatedToSpringTest() {
        TodoBusinessImpl todoBusinessImpl = new TodoBusinessImpl(businessManager);
        Mockito.when(todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("test"))
    .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("test"));
    }
}
```

This is the test class. Getting exception that org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by getDetails()

Comment: please write code of your test class to look into it

Comment: @DhawalKapil test class added

Comment: you are mocking the response you are testing?

Comment: @dhawal BusinessMnager is mocked. I want to test method of TodoBusinessImpl

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the method that you're testing not mock it's behavior "not tell it what to do when it's called".
Instead of:

```
Mockito.when(todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("test")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("test"));
```

You should do this:

```
 List<String> list = todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("test");
 // print list or assert it's content to make sure you're getting the right response
```